# What options are available to cover a gap in a stone countertop left when a slightly smaller stovetop was installed?

Tags: stove, countertops, patch

We installed a new drop-in stainles steel stovetop into a hole in our stone countertop.  This has left a 1/4" to 1/2" gap in the rear, since it's not quite as deep as the old stovetop was.

What options are there to make this hole look better?  It's not really very visible, so it doesn't have to look perfect, but something better than a gap would be nice.

Comment: please add a clear  closeup picture of the gap, not a picture of the whole gap

Comment: Is the front edge already at the edge of the cutout? Maybe it could move back if something was added to resupport the front? I will answer if it could be moved....

Comment: It's pushed as far backward as it can reasonably be done without leaving a gap at the front.  The front overlap is around 1/4", and the rear gap is 1/2" to 3/4".

Answer (score 2):

(I was lucky with my last cooktop - it was slightly smaller and my plumber was able to cut the counter a little bit to make it fit.)

With a stainless steel cooktop, I would look for stainless steel - or at least "shiny metal" to match. [Something like this one on Amazon](https://amzn.to/2Js1JOS):

[image: Stainless Steel Counter Gap Filler]

Definitely measure first! If a filler piece is too long, you can cut it down, but if it is too short then it won't work very well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should hide that gap, there are many options available. Just google " stovetop gap filler" and you will see many options. https://tinyurl.com/yxthj7gw